# User generated input field using javascript, how do I populate their data back in the input field if validation fails

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, validation

I have an input field section that requires one field to be filled in but if they want to add more fields they hit a + button and it generates a new input field.  They can also hit a - button to delete it.  How do I perform validations on these user generated input fields?  When I hit the submit button on the form the user generated fields disappear, so i cant re-display the data they filled in so they can see what they did wrong and change it.

```
<div id="pick_style">
<label for="pick_up_location">Pick Up Location(s)</label>
<input type="text" name="pick_up_location_1" 
value="<?php if (isset($_POST['pick_up_location_1'])) 
{ echo $_POST['pick_up_location_1']; } ?>"list="pick_up_location" />
<datalist name="pick_up_location" id="pick_up_location">
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($pickup_location_initial)){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['store_city'] . ',' 
. ' ' . $row['store_state'] . ' ' .$row['store_num']; ?>">
<?php
}
?>
</datalist>

<input type="button" id="add_pickup()" onClick="add_pickup()" value="+" />
</div>
```

This is the initial pick up location which is required and is easy to display back to the user if validation fails with value=isset $_POST variable.  But when a user wants to add an additional pick up location they hit a + button which triggers this code:

```
var p = 1; 
function add_pickup(){

if (p <= 4){

p++; 

var div = document.createElement('div'); 
div.innerHTML = '<label for="pick_up_location"></label>
<input type="text"   name="pick_up_location_'+p+'" list="pick_up_location" />
<datalist name="pick_up_location" id="pick_up_location">
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultpickup)){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['store_city'] . ',' . ' ' .
$row['store_state'] . ' ' .   $row['store_num']; ?>"><?php } ?></datalist>
<input type="button" id="add_pickup()" onClick="add_pickup()" value="+" />
<input type="button" onClick="removePick(this)" value="-" />';
document.getElementById('pick_style').appendChild(div);
}
 }

function removePick(div){

document.getElementById('pick_style').removeChild( div.parentNode )
p--; 

}
```

How would I re-display the users input data if they fill out 2, 3, 4, or 5 fields if a validations fails and I want to make it easy on them to fix by showing them what they put in before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over `pick_up_location_1, ..., pick_up_location_4` on the server side and create HTML with `-` (minus) buttons:

```
<div id="pick_style">
<?php for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) { ?>
<?php $key = 'pick_up_location_' + $i; ?>
<?php if (isset($_POST[$key])) { ?>
  <label for="pick_up_location">Pick Up Location(s)</label>
  <input type="text" name="<?php echo $key; ?>"
    value="<?php if (isset($_POST[$key])) { echo $_POST[$key]; } ?>" list="<?php echo $key; ?>" />
  <datalist name="<?php echo $key; ?>" id="<?php echo $key; ?>">
  <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($pickup_location_initial)) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['store_city'] . ',' . ' ' . $row['store_state'] . ' ' . $row['store_num']; ?>">
  <?php } ?>
</datalist>
<input type="button" onClick="removePick(this)" value="-" />
<?php } /* if */ ?>
<?php } /* for */ ?>
<input type="button" id="add_pickup()" onClick="add_pickup()" value="+" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  This started me down the right path!